# Deleting qwtsymbol

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm making constelattion plot on qwt, and using qwtsymbols in that. When i'm closing my application, with these symbols on qwtplot, it throws me error in these lines:

```
  ~PrivateData()
{
 #ifndef QWT_NO_SVG
    delete svg.renderer;
 #endif
}
```

Where i can define this QWT_NO_SVG?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt project file (.pro) then you can define in that file as shown below.

```
DEFINES += QWT_NO_SVG
```

Comment: no, i don't use .pro file. Maybe i can define somewhere in main.c?

Comment: Yes in the c file you can define. #define QWT_NO_SVG 1

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't help. Now program throws an exception, when it tries to delete the qwtsymbol. For some reason, the symbol memory address becomes empty, when i close application, and this causes the delete trouble.

Comment: And, to be honest, this error occures even when i use this: ui.constellation_plot->detachItems(QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotMarker);